# Formula for row index of a minimal distance matrix?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am working on the following problem:

given a matrix of `M` rows, I calculate a minimal distance matrix containing the absolute differences among all the possible couples of rows.

> In order to make the distance matrix as minimal as possible, I do compute only the differences
> between the row `I` and the following rows `J`.

I now want to find a formula to know at which row `K` on the distance matrix is mapped the difference of the original matrix rows `I` and `J`.

The new matrix will have `M(M-1)/2` rows.

E.g.

$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 8 & 3 & 7\\
5 & 4 & 8 & 6\\
3 & 5 & 4 & 3\\
2 & 3 & 7 & 4\\
\end{matrix}
$$

will result in the following minimal distance matrix:

$$
\begin{matrix}
5 & 4 & 5 & 1\\
3 & 3 & 1 & 4\\
2 & 5 & 4 & 3\\
2 & 1 & 4 & 3\\
3 & 1 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Considering this example, the formula I am looking for should return the following values of `K`, given `I`, `J` and `M` in input:

$$
\begin{matrix}
I & J & K\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 3 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 3 & 5\\
\end{matrix}
$$

> I am considering the rows and columns index as starting from zero.

**Update**

Each row `I` of matrix A `M*N` has exactly `L` rows in the minimal distance matrix:

$$
L = M - I - 1
$$